# Does Cassandra 3.0 provide Materialized Views

Tags: cassandra, materialized-views, cassandra-3.0

I am happy that Cassandra 3.0 is out now and thought i'd check the documentation.
[This documentation page](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/features.html) states that 3.0 offers support for materialized views.

Is this feature still in progress (why then stated in the "new features" section?) or how is it used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Theres a good walk through with some "when to use, when not to use" points:
http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/new-in-cassandra-3-0-materialized-views
https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/refCreateMV.html

1.2 is far too old. Latest CQL documentation is for 2.2 http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/cql3 but thats still too old, the 3.0 versions doesn't seem to be added yet (3.0 is very new yet).

Comment: I read that blog already. Since then I waited for 3.0, since i'm very interested in the materialized views feature. You are right that CQL1.2 is not the right one - i linked it because it was linked on the Cassandra downloads page. However I already tried to use the syntax from the blog examples and CQLSH tells me that it doesn't know the materialized keyword :(

Comment: are you sure your using both C* 3.0 and the 3.0 version of CQLSH? Whats output from cqlsh when you connect?

Comment: Yes. For testing i'm currently using the official docker image available. (https://hub.docker.com/_/cassandra/)